# How to restrict who can post on a channel in Slack?

Tags: slack

I want to have a special channel primarily to post company's announcement in my Slack team, and I don't want anybody, except me and a select few people, to post in that channel, to not distract the channel viewer from the announcement content. But I still want everybody to be able to see the content of the channel (e.g. making it one of the default channels new user automatically joins to). Can I do that in Slack? How? Or is there an alternative or workaround to achieve the similar result?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can restrict who can post to the #general channel on your team settings, in http://my.slack.com/admin/settings#permissions

Available restrictive options are *Team Owners and Admins* or *Team Owners only*.

You can rename #general to something more appropriate like "#announcements".

Currently, you cannot restrict posting rights to other public channels than #general.

More information is available on https://get.slack.help/hc/en-us/articles/220105027-The-general-channel

Comment: Ouw, great information nonetheless. Thanks!

Comment: Since this post was written you can now apply these changes to any channel _if_ you are on at least the Plus plan: https://slack.com/intl/en-au/blog/transformation/managing-slack-at-scale-announcement-channels-and-new-admin-apis

Answer (score 2):

There still is no way to do it inside Slack :( but I've worked around this by using a simple Slack App using Amazon AWS Lambda. The actual Lambda python function could just as easily be modified to run on some other server, of course.

https://github.com/flipswitchingmonkey/SlackMonitor

Answer (score 0):

You can do this now in Slack

- Create your channel.
- Right click on channel name in the side bar, and choose `Open channel details`
- Click `Settings | Posting Permissions`
- Select the `You and Specific People` radio button, and add team members that are allowed to post to this channel.
- Uncheck `Allow Threads`

Answer (score -1):

we also need to have some channels that only certain people can post and readonly for others, so I've wrote very simple script that does it for us. You can take a look https://github.com/ypogorelova/slack_blockbot